# Executing a binary package from a Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

There's an open source poker library called Poker Eval that I'm trying to integrate into my Heroku Rails app.

Locally, I added the package I'm interested in (called "pokenum") to my app's root directory and can successfully execute it using the console:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.2)
1.9.2-p290 :001 > `pwd`
=> "/Users/matt/testapp\n" 
1.9.2-p290 :003 > `/Users/matt/testapp/pokenum As Ah - Ts Th`
=> "Holdem Hi: 1712304 enumerated boards\ncards     win   %win      lose  %lose       tie   %tie        EV\nAs Ah 1390140  81.19    314314  18.36      7850   0.46     0.814\nTs Th  314314  18.36   1390140  81.19      7850   0.46     0.186\n"
```

However, when I upload the app to Heroku and follow the same steps, I get a "Errno::ENOEXEC: Exec format error":

```
$ heroku run console
Running console attached to terminal... up, run.3
Loading production environment (Rails 3.1.2)
irb(main):001:0> `pwd`
=> "/app\n"
irb(main):002:0> `/app/pokenum As Ah - Ts Th`
Errno::ENOEXEC: Exec format error - /app/pokenum As Ah - Ts Th
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'
from (irb):2
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Seems like there's probably a simple solution, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Most of the Google results for this error message indicate that there's a problem with the path name, but based on the pwd results, I seem to have the full path. Maybe it has something to do with Heroku's architecture?

Any idea what might be causing this or how I can troubleshoot it further?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to execute binary on heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979704/how-to-execute-binary-on-heroku)

Comment: You can't run an OSX binary on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mu was correct, you can't compile a file on Snow Leopard and expect it to run on Heroku, which uses Ubuntu 10.04.

I wound up downloading VMWare Fusion and an image of Ubuntu and compiling the code on there, which I then was able to execute on Heroku.