# Generate PDF from ODT

Tags: django, heroku, pdf-generation, odt

I use appy pod for reporting in my django app.

At this moment, I need to generate pdf file instead odt document.

pod is able to generate pdf if OO is available, but this is not my case because app runs in heroku provider.

Someone knows a way to convert .odt to a pdf in this scenario?

Comment: Indirect answer to your question: Can you use HTML instead of ODT? If so, you should checkoout wkhtmltopdf: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: hi jeremy. thanks about your appoinment. I prefear appy pod, it ia a really smart solution, also I have control over pagination and i can reset page number over sections. do you have expertise in you suggested project?

Comment: I don't have any expertise. But you could try including Open Office as an executable in your repo. Here are some ways that Ruby folks have done something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979704/how-to-execute-binary-on-heroku

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I will ask to apply people if this may be a solution. Nice starting point.

Answer (score 2):

One idea could be to deploy a dedicated Web API somewhere else, with topdfserver : https://github.com/AntoineCezar/topdfserver/tree/develop :)

Comment: thanks. I will learn more about this. +1. be patient before check it as solution.

Comment: The link provided no longer seems to be valid. Here is the latest I've found on github:
https://github.com/makinacorpus/topdfserver/tree/develop