# How to use CMU Sphinx speech recognition with Ruby application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cmusphinx

I'm searching for how to use CMU Sphinx with Ruby (Rails) application. I need very simple task - I have an mp3 file and I want get it transcribed into text.

How can I implement this easiest way? I dont' know C/C++ and my task isn't so big to learn C/C++ for it :)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CMUSphinx provides several interfaces you can use to leverage speech recognition features. Some of them might be more suitable for you, some less:

1. Use command-line tools and execute them as an external binaries from Rails application to obtain the required results. The tool to execute is *pocketsphinx_continuous*. For more information on how to invoke binaries from Rails see the question:
   [how to execute binary on heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979704/how-to-execute-binary-on-heroku)
2. You can invoke Sphinx4 framework from JRuby using JVM, see for example on how to use Sphinx4 from [JRuby](http://jruby.org/): http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4#writing_scripts
3. You can implement the pocketsphinx bindings using [SWIG](http://swig.org/). The easy part is that the swig wrappers for Python already exist as a part of the pocketsphinx, you just need to use SWIG to generate Ruby wrappers: https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/code/11643/tree/trunk/pocketsphinx/swig/
4. Finally, you can implement a REST web using Java REST frameworks to convert audio to text using CMUSphinx tools and invoke the sevice from your Ruby code. For more information see information how to use [REST from Rails](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cb08016/)
   This way your can make your system really scalable.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently created a gem for doing just this:

https://github.com/watsonbox/pocketsphinx-ruby

It uses the Ruby Foreign Function Interface (FFI) to interact directly with libpocketsphinx.

Comment: Hey Howard, I'm very interested in using your gem, but I fount it really hard to set up. I compiled both pocketsphinx and sphinx but I don't know what to do next... How do I tell ruby where these files are? Do I need to put them in a specific location?

Comment: Hey I found many words are not recognising correctly using that gem... but thanks that's a nice gem

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into this Ruby-based speech recognition web service that uses PocketSphinx:

https://github.com/alumae/ruby-pocketsphinx-server