# Cannot Run PocketSphinx from Ruby

Tags: ruby, cmusphinx

I am trying to run PocketSphinx from Ruby. What I did is run a terminal command from Ruby. Like this:

```
cmd = "pocketsphinx_continuous \
        -lm /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en_US/hub4.5000.DMP \
        -dict /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en_US/cmu07a.dic\
        -infile ~/Path/FileName.wav"
output = `#{cmd}`
puts output
```

This works well if there is a file input. However, when I tried to process streaming audio, like speaking from microphone, I just delete the line of "-infile". In this case it does not work anymore. PocketSphinx processes, but it never shows "Ready" like usually.

FYI, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Ruby 2.0.

Do you have any ideas about what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

That's because reading the micrphone input assumes that you should end the process manually. There are two options: to send SIGINT to the process upon a timeout or to compile a Ruby library from the SWIG interface. You can learn more about the latter reading about [Python interface](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2014/08/python-decoding-example/) for pocketsphinx and looking at the [sources](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/tree/master/swig).

Also, see this [comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13308007/1746434) regarding the use of CMU Sphinx in Ruby.

Comment: Thank you Alexander!                                                I solved this problem by use exec(cmd) instead of #{} and it worked. But I still want to know what do you mean by "send SIGINT" to process upon a timeout. Is there any more specific guide?     Thanx!